# SpringBoot - i want to show login button for only users that are not logged-in

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am currently looking for a solution on how to not show the login button  when a user is fully authenticated. This is for a personal project that I am doing. I want  users to not be able to view the login button if they are connected, i already tried to look in the thymeleaf documentation i didn't find an answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Spring Security, you can do something like:

```html
              <li th:ref="navbar-item" sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()">
                <a th:text="'Login'" th:href="@{/login}"/>
              </li>
```

For the complete context, take a look at my
[blog article](https://blog.hcf.dev/article/2020-10-31-spring-boot-part-07)
and the corresponding source on
[GitHub](https://github.com/allen-ball/spring-boot-web-server/tree/trunk/part-07).